# Label attribute in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, label, android-manifest, motorola, app-launcher

I have a manifest with its label declared so the launcher label is different from the Main Activity (the one that is launched at start).
It was working fine, but today I saw on a friends phone it took the activity's label instead.
I have no idea what could be happening.
If it is of any help, the phone was a Motorola Razr.

Here's the relevant portion of the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.app.eventiame.EventiameApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.eventiame.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: That IS strange.  I have an app set up like that.  Different icon and label for each Activity.  And it's set up just like yours.  I wonder if I will run into this.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrote

```
 android:name="com.app.eventiame.EventiameApp"
```

instead you can just specify your app name here as below

```
android:name="EventiameApp"
```

Comment: That is the name of the application class, but what's it has to do with the label?

Comment: I think based on your target sdk it may causes problem , You can specify "Appname" string here too